# with enum switch -- Swift --- one can go far

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement, swift2

Got this problem that's really bugging me. I've been watching Stack Overflow to try find a solution, but couldn't find anything.

```
enum SortMails {
    case SortedMailAsc
    case SortedMailDec
}

var sortedMails: SortMails!

@IBAction func sortMails(sender: AnyObject) {

    switch sortedMails! { /* this is where i get fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value */

        case .SortedMailAsc:
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("sortedMailAsc", object: nil)
        case .SortedMailDec:
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("sortedMailDec", object: nil)

        }
}
```

Basically, I want a button to have two functions, first press sort UITableView Asc, second press sort UITableView Dec

Comment: You need to give `sortedMails` a value.  `var sortedMails = SortMails.SortedMailAsc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sort = "Asc"

@IBAction func sortMails(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("sortedMail" + sort, object: nil)

    sort = (sort == "Asc") ? "Dec" : "Asc"
}
```

The questioner wanted a button that would sort ascending when touched, then descending when touched again.

The code above uses a string to hold the sort order. It's initialized to "Asc" for ascending.

When the button is touched, it posts a notification "sortedMailAsc".

Then it changes the sort order to "Dec" for descending (this should be "Desc" but the questioner used "Dec").

The second time the button is touched, the code posts a notification "sortedMailDec" and changes the sort order back to "Asc".

The idea was to keep the code simple and avoid repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to set a value for **sortedMails**. What I recommend, though, is to use optionals.

```
enum SortMails {
   case SortedMailAsc
   case SortedMailDec
}

var sortedMails: SortMails?

@IBAction func sortMails(sender: AnyObject) {

      if let sortedMailsValue = sortedMails {
          switch sortedMailsValue {
             case .SortedMailAsc:
                 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("sortedMailAsc", object: nil)
             case .SortedMailDec:
                 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("sortedMailDec", object: nil)

          }
      }
}
```